# Basket Option pricing of two stocks

Tags: options, option-pricing, monte-carlo, basket

I am trying to use Monte Carlo simulation to price arithmetic basket option consisting of two stocks. There seems to be something wrong in my implementation. According to the inputs

```
S1=100, S2=100, K=100, v1=30%, v2=30%, r=5%, T=3, M=100000, type=call
```

the value should be `24.345`. But for me it's coming out to be `21.913`. Here is my implementation:

```
dt = T
drift1 = exp((r-0.5*v1*v1)*dt)
drift2 = exp((r-0.5*v2*v2)*dt)

S1next = 0.0
S2next = 0.0
arithPayOff = numpy.empty(M, dtype=float)

scipy.random.seed([100])

for i in range(0,M,1):
    growthFactor1 = drift1 * exp(v1*sqrt(dt)*scipy.random.randn(1))
    S1next = S1 * growthFactor1
    growthFactor2 = drift2 * exp(v2*sqrt(dt)*scipy.random.randn(1))
    S2next = S2 * growthFactor2

    # Arithmetic mean
    arithMean = 0.5 * (S1next+S2next)
    arithPayOff[i] = exp(-r*T) * max(callOrPut*(arithMean-K), 0)

# Standard monte carlo
Pmean = numpy.mean(arithPayOff)
Pstd = numpy.std(arithPayOff)

confmc = [Pmean - 1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M), Pmean + 1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M)]
return numpy.mean(confmc)
```

Comment: Why dt = T? This implies a time interval of 3 years. dt - should be possibly small

Comment: @cykor21 we take time step to be 1 as need to simulate stock prices at maturity T only

Comment: What's the correlation between the two stock returns?

Comment: @AlexC it is 0.5

Comment: This is an inefficient way to calculate the value.  Instead do quadrature on the 1-d marginals, with the Black-Scholes formula as the integrand.

Comment: are the driving Brownian motions of the two stocks correlated?

Comment: @Gordon yes their correlation is +0.5

Comment: Brian B's comment is very much on point.  Also, where in your code is the 0.5 correlation coming into play?  Monte Carlo is still useful for testing whether you did the integrals correctly  when it comes to Brian B's comment.  Probably don't even need to do quadrature - may be a straightforward analytic solution if you are patient and good at messy math.

Comment: I (also) don't see the code that makes them correlated 0.5, the returns look independent to me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that the correlation is completely ignored. I would replace the loop by the following piece of code:

```
for i in range(0,M,1):
    Rand1 = scipy.random.randn(1)
    Rand2 = scipy.random.randn(1)
    growthFactor1 = drift1 * exp(v1 * sqrt(dt) * Rand1)
    S1next = S1 * growthFactor1
    growthFactor2 = drift2 * exp(v2 * sqrt(dt) * (0.5 * Rand1 + sqrt(0.75) * Rand2))
    S2next = S2 * growthFactor2

    # Arithmetic mean
    arithMean = 0.5 * (S1next+S2next)
    arithPayOff[i] = exp(-r * T) * max(callOrPut * (arithMean - K), 0)
```

Basically, two correlated standard normal random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with correlation $\rho$ can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
X_1 &= \xi,\\
X_2 &= \rho\, \xi + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\, \eta,
\end{align*}
where $\xi$ and $\eta$ are two independent standard normal random variables.

Comment: @stud91 - worth looking into the Cholesky Decomposition for generating correlated random number sequences.

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCanCode in the case of two random variables this is the cholesky decomposition...

Comment: @will - Gordon added the equations with $X_1$ and $X_2$ after the suggestion, but stud91 should probably look it up in general given his error in the code he posted.

Comment: Ah okay. And that is true.